# Linking to a TimThumb thumbnail in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, href, echo

I have a WordPress Theme that uses TimThumb to create thumbnails. 
I want to have two links:

1. A link to the full size image
2. A link to a thumbnail of the image

I have figured out I can link to the full size image like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $thumbnail["fullpath"]; ?>">Link to full size image</a>
```

But how do I link to a thumbnail of the image?

Comment: add the line `<?php print_r($thumbnail); ?>` below the `a` tag, then view the source and look for the array, as cant give the answer as dont know whats in the array

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it displays `Array ( [thumb] => http://mysite.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/test.jpg [use_timthumb] => 1 [fullpath] => http://mysite.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/test.jpg )`

Comment: looks like TimThumb is not setup properly, you could look in wp-content/uploads/2011/05/ for a thumbnail of the file, if one exists then manipulate the $thumbnail[fullpath] to find the thumb

Comment: As you can tell I'm not an experienced coder, the thumbnails exist in the correct directory, so lets say the thumbnail I want to link to is called 'test_300x300.jpg' how would I link to that?

Comment: its ok, `<a href="<?php echo str_replace('.jpg','_300x300.jpg',$thumbnail['fullpath']); ?>">Link to thumb</a>`

Comment: Excellent, that worked. Very much appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="<?php echo str_replace('.jpg','_300x300.jpg',$thumbnail['fullpath']); ?>">Link to thumb</a>
```